# Grid Columns Prop Not Working Semantic UI

Tags: reactjs, web-applications, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I'm trying to only have one column in a grid. But the prop columns={1} is not working. And the columns are not taking the whole width of the window.

This is the code where I return the component.

```
return (
        <Grid columns={1} textAlign='center' container divided='vertically'>
            <Grid.Column width={6}>
                <Search fluid size='huge'
                    loading = {isLoading}
                    onResultSelect = {this.handleResultSelect}
                    onSearchChange = {this.handleSearchChange}
                    results = {results}
                    value = {value} />
                {this.state.rides}
            </Grid.Column>
            <Grid.Column width={10}>
                <Image src={faker.image.avatar()} style={{ backgroundSize: 'cover' }} />
            </Grid.Column> 
        </Grid>
    );
```

Image of how it looks at present.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In fact, it's wrong usage of props, `columns` and `width` can't be combined. Take a look on [this issue](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/issues/1886) on Github, it contains more info about `Grid`. Also, you can check [official docs](https://semantic-ui.com/collections/grid.html) of SUI.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the `width` prop you have on your `Grid.Column` sub-components. The width for each child column should add up to the total number of columns you have specified.

You could add multiple `Grid.Column` components to the following layout and they will all appear in a single column:

```
<Grid
  columns={1}
  textAlign="center"
  container
  divided="vertically"
>
    <Grid.Column>
      ...
    </Grid.Column>
    <Grid.Column>
      ...
    </Grid.Column>
</Grid>
```

What is the result you are trying to achieve?

I set up an example to play around with at the following URL: https://codesandbox.io/s/pyvqv1k01m